# Bind data into a list MVC controller

Tags: list, model-view-controller

This is my controller. I have a view in a list format but it is giving error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'MvcDemo.Models.Employee'    G:\MvcApp\MvcDemo\MvcDemo\Controllers\EmployeeController.cs 18

```
    public ActionResult Details()
    {
        EmployeeContext ec = new EmployeeContext();
        Employee e1 = ec.employee.ToList();


        return View(e1);
    }
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to as follows.

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    EmployeeContext ec = new EmployeeContext();
    List<Employee> e1 = ec.employee.ToList();


    return View(e1);
}
```